# Spring repository query returns the same value over and over

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc

I'm having an issue with Spring when I feed in a native query, some of the data it returns is correct, but other fields are returned as the same value over and over.

The project has Company objects, and each company object has a list of Sentiment objects, representing headlines posted about the company, the date that the headline was posted, the companies stock price that day, and the value that a neural network believes the stock price will move by in the next 24 hours (but that's not that important right now.

The problem is that when I use spring to pull the sentiment data from the database, all sentiment objects are returned with id=0 stockprice=0 and all with the same date. [Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdvXy.png) shows that all id=0, all stock prices=0, all dates = 2020-02-27, but headlines are changing as expected. Here's the query I use:

```
@Query(value=" SELECT sentiment.* FROM sentiment, company, company_sentiment WHERE(company.id=company_sentiment.Company_id) AND (sentiment.id=company_sentiment.sentimentData_id) AND (company.id='%' || :keyword || '%')",
            nativeQuery=true)
    public List<Sentiment> getSentiment(@Param("keyword") String keyword);
```

Contrary to this, the data is fine inside the database.
The dates and prediction being the same across a few days are fine, as data overlaps but the fact that it's always zero means somethings wrong with it being read into the web app
As a result of this,[the website I made for the project looks pointless.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkAhc.png).

Have you ever encountered a problem like this?

Comment: Step 0: Only use `nativeQuery` as a last resort. Assuming this is Spring Data JPA (which it looks like), it seems something like `public List<Sentiment> findBySentimentDataCompanyId(String keyword)` might generate a more-reliable query.

Answer (score 0):

try this: in the argument keyword in the method don't use `@Param("keyword")`

but like this

`public List<Sentiment> getSentiment(String keyword);`

and in the query instead of `:keyword` use `?1`

I hope it helps